# Problem with the usage of the generic type of List

Tags: java, list, generics

I was trying to use one method(called readDataPairs) and based on a boolean value i wanted to return the proper list.The problem is that i get an error and i dont know hoe to fix it.It says:

"The method add(capture#2-of ?) in the type List<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (DataPair)"

My code is this:

```java
public List<?> readDataPairs(boolean processReturn) throws IOException {
    List<?> pairs = null;
    if (processReturn) {
        pairs = new ArrayList<DataPair>();
        try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(WriteFile.dataPairFileName, "r")) {
            long fileLength = raf.length();
            long bytesRead = 0;
            while (bytesRead < fileLength) {
                int recordCount = raf.readInt();
                bytesRead += 4;
                for (int i = 0; i < recordCount; i++) {
                    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytesPerDataPage);
                    raf.read(bb.array());
                    bb.rewind();
                    DataPair dataPair = SerializeAndVers.deserializeDataPair(bb);
                    pairs.add(SerializeAndVers.deserializeDataPair(bb));
                } //compiler's error
                bytesRead += bytesPerDataPage;
            }
        }
    } else {
        pairs = new ArrayList<DataPagePair>();
        try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(WriteFile.dataPairFileName, "r")) {
            long fileLength = raf.length();
            long bytesRead = 0;
            int pageCount = 0;
            while (bytesRead < fileLength) {
                int recordCount = raf.readInt();
                bytesRead += 4;
                pageCount++;
                for (int i = 0; i < recordCount; i++) {
                    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytesPerDataPage);
                    raf.read(bb.array());
                    bb.rewind();
                    DataPair dataPair = SerializeAndVers.deserializeDataPair(bb);
                    pairs.add(new DataPagePair(dataPair.getKey(), pageCount)); //compiler's error
                }
                bytesRead += bytesPerDataPage;
            }
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

The class used for serialize and vers is the following:

```java
public class SerializeAndVers {
    
    public static ByteBuffer serializeDataPair(DataPair dataPair) {
        int stringLength = dataPair.getString().length();
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8 + stringLength);
        bb.putInt(dataPair.getKey());
        bb.putInt(stringLength);
        bb.put(dataPair.getString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
        bb.flip();
        return bb;
    }

    public static DataPair deserializeDataPair(ByteBuffer bb ) {
        int key = bb.getInt();
        int stringLength = bb.getInt();
        byte[] stringBytes = new byte[stringLength];
        bb.get(stringBytes, 0, stringLength);
        String string = new String(stringBytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        return new DataPair(key, string);
    }
}
```

Any help would be usefull.

PS.I also used `addAll` but it also didn't work.

Comment: can you please add to your question, where the compiler complains with the error message? (maybe best with a comment in the code)

Comment: **Caution:** `raf.read(bb.array())` will eventually bite you (no pun intended), because there is no guarantee it will fill the array.  That’s why the `read` method returns the number of bytes that were actually read.  You may want to use the [readFully](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readFully(byte%5B%5D)) method of RandomAccessFile instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<?>` means "A List, but I don't know what it can and cannot contain".

Since the list contains an unknown type, you're not allowed to add anything to it since there is no way to be sure if it's the correct type or not. (The only exception is `null` since it's valid no matter what the actual type parameter is.)

So, if you do something like this

```java
List<?> pairs;
pairs = new ArrayList<DataPair>();
pairs.add(pair);
return pairs;
```

You, the programmer, know that it's a list of `DataPair`, but Java doesn't know that since the type of the variable is what matters, not what it's initialized to.

Your main options (that doesn't introduce unnecessary type unsafety) would either be to write...

```java
List<DataPair> pairs;
pairs = new ArrayList<DataPair>();
pairs.add(pair);
return pairs;
```

...or...

```java
List<?> pairs;
List<DataPair> dataPairList = new ArrayList<DataPair>();
pairs = dataPairList;
dataPairList.add(pair);
return pairs;
```

Answer (score 0):

You define:

```
List<?> pairs = null;
```

So there is your error `capture#2-of ?`, as the type for pairs is set as `List<?>`.

```
pairs.add(SerializeAndVers.deserializeDataPair(bb));
```

doesn't match the capture, so either

1 - don't use generics for this use case.

```
public List readDataPairs(boolean processReturn) throws IOException {
    List pairs = null;
    . . .
    return pairs;
}
```

2 - Create a "common" interface for `DataPair` and `DataPagePair`, let us say `Pair` and declare it as

```
public List<Pair> readDataPairs(boolean processReturn) throws IOException {
    List<Pair> pairs = null;
    . . .
    return pairs;
}
```